# GRASS v.generalize method=douglas not working as expected

Tags: grass-gis

I'm frustrated with v.generalize trying to simplify polygons. Those polygons stem from ArcGIS's raster to vector function (imported into GRASS from Shapefile), so they are pretty zigzag like this:

[image: Zigzaged]

Trying to simplify them with

```
v.generalize input=polygons -c method=douglas threshold=0.1 layer=-1 output=polygons_dp
```

Leads to a weird result like this:

[image: simplified]

Some isles and even partially borders remain untouched. Tried v.clean, v.build.polylines before simplifying, but same result.

Comment: Why are you trying with GRASS and not with other tools such QGIS simplify geometry?

Comment: I'm trying with GRASS because I need topology. Simplifying the Shapefile with QGIS' built-in simplifying tool leads to holes between polygons.

Comment: Ok I understand. In such case I use FME, but maybe you can use GRASS v.clean to clean the topology after simplifying the Shapefile with QGIS if it is easier. It is just an idea...

Comment: Tried that also already but got stuck with eliminating the holes in GRASS: Not only holes are eliminated but small polygons that fall under threshold also. I read about this [workaround](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/H2CPn16mSm5BgZkUZfWe) but I would like to clarify the v.generalize issue first. Maybe it's a bug in GRASS!?

Comment: DP belongs to the simplification algorithms while you want to use smoothing (also provided by v.generalize)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally got a workaround for the problem, based on Micha's suggestion (thank you!) to import the raster to GRASS and vectorize it there.

1 Import Raster:

`r.in.gdal input=raster.tif output=raster`

2 Vectorize (option -s leads to slightly smoothed 45-degree edges):

`r.to.vect -s input=raster output=vector_blue feature=area`

3 Generalize with Douglas to get rid of excessive points:

`v.generalize input=vector_blue -c method=douglas threshold=0.05 output=vector_green`

4 Smooth with Chaiken's algorithm to get smoother curves:

`v.generalize input=vector_green -c method=chaiken threshold=0.1 output=vector_orange`

5 Remove small polygons (area in m² if you have a lat/lon region):

`v.clean tool=rmarea thresh=1000000000 input=vector_orange output=vector_red`

[image: The result as animated gif]

Answer (score 2):

If you can go back to the original raster, and import that into GRASS, then the module r.to.vect has a "-s" flag for smoothing the output vector boundaries. No generalize needed. 
Check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/how-to-smooth-large-vector-polygons-from-raster) StackExchange question for a way to convert raster to vector in Arc and get smoother boundaries.

Comment: As far as I understand r.to.vect -s leads only to 45 degree edges. That's not enough smoothing since I want to smooth my vectors further in a third step, using chaiken's algorithm (the vectors are going to be prepared for print). Therefore I have to reduce the number of points first by douglas's algorithm. My question is if there's a bug in GRASS's v.generalize causing the weird result above (leaving out some isles and boundarys) or if there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Back to this topic: you really wanted to apply "smoothing" here, see  http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.generalize.html#smoothing and not what you have tried (douglas). Use instead e.g. "chaiken":

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.generalize.html#smoothing-example

BTW: we added the possibility to generate an "error" map which contains those lines which cannot be simplified due to topological conflicts. Like this you can now easily identify issues in order to optimize the control parameters for simplification, smoothing, or displacement.

Comment: Thanks Markus! Yes, I really wanted smoothing. The idea behind first using DP simplification ist that the chaiken algorithm (which is quite slow on large datasets) speeds up if it's feeded with a simplified version of the original dataset. My input data is a worldwide raster with 1 arc-minute resolution (00:01:00). It would be great if you could point me to other possibilities of speeding up chaiken smoothing (and avoid topological conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve the topology you can also have a look to [Mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/). This is a javascript [command line tool](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Introduction-to-the-Command-Line-Tool), but also [a web interface](https://mapshaper.org/) and can be accessed in R through the [rmapshaper package](https://github.com/ateucher/rmapshaper).

[image]

Image from [here](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Simplification-Tips): 5% simplification; left: Visvalingam simplification (default in mapshaper), right: Douglas-Peucker simplification.
Works extremely fast and is as easy as this line of code:

```
mapshaper input.shp -simplify 10% -o out.shp
```