# Smoothing out polygons without gaps?

Tags: qgis, polygon, smoothing

I'm converting a raster data to vector data.

The problem is similar to this:
[How to smooth large vector polygons from Raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/how-to-smooth-large-vector-polygons-from-raster)

But what I need to know is how can I handle out the gaps that are formed between the polygons?

I want the gaps to be filled with the polygon near to it.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].